# identifying shapes in spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, euclidean-geometry

[image]

I don't understand how to approach this problem. My book showed me how to plot spherical coordinates, convert from spherical to rectangular and vice versa, integrate in spherical coordinates and showed me a few basic shapes but I still have no idea what this is implying. (number 7) How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Look closely at the conversion equations.  If that fails, try graphing $r\cos \theta = 1$ in polar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by definition $z=\rho cos\phi=1$ is the plane z=1

Comment: oh. ............